# jsf lightweight application server

Tags: java, webserver, web-application, lightweight

I need to run a web application based on JSF, JPA and EJB. But the server has very limited resources:

CPU: VIA C7 Esther 1000Mhz

RAM: 1GB

HDD: 500GB 5400RPM

Now, is there any particular lightweight java application server that can perform honestly on that configuration?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[Jetty](http://eclipse.org/jetty/) will run on that set-up beautifully. But ultimately performance will depend on the application it is asked to run.